# fadeTo() takes effect only after certain amount of delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple JS code where I try to fade out a certain element (a  tag with the id "intro-section") after the user scrolls a certain number (400 in this case) from the top and then fade in the said element when the user goes above certain pixels from the top.

Here is the JS, JQuery code that I'm using:

The problem is that the fadeTo() function shows the animation effect only after a stupidly long amount of time (the fade-out starts 20 seconds after I cross the 400px mark and the fade-in process after I go back up, starts after another 20 seconds). I want it to instantly fade in and fade out, right after I go more than 400px or less than 400px. (I don't want to use the fadeIn() and fadeOut() function because they set the display to none).

Here is a minute-long video of the entire process:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXwmi.jpg

I'm not sure if fadeTo() has some kind of automatically added delay in it or if I'm doing something wrong.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log(y);

  if (y > 400) {
    console.log('fading out');
    $('#intro-section').fadeTo(400, 0.0);
    console.log('done fading out');
  } else {
    console.log('fading in');
    $('#intro-section').fadeTo(400, 1.0);
    console.log('done fading in');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

#intro-section {
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>
<div style="height: 300px">
  Scroll down!
</div>

<div id="intro-section">
  Intro
</div>

<div style="height: 100vh">
</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I cant see the video. Please check it. And if #intro-section has any css, please share it.

Comment: @OsmanDurdag Can you please tell me what exactly you mean by not being able to see the video? Is the link not loading?

Comment: Yes, it is not loading, I wait and then the icon appears when the picture is not uploaded

Comment: I created a snippet from your code, can you edit it so we can see the delay and see the effect for ourselves?

Comment: @OsmanDurdag I have tried re-uploading and changed the link, please tell me if this one works or not.

Comment: @cloned Sorry for the late reply, I have edited the snippet and tried to emulate my problem.

Comment: I still cant see the video, but now you have added snippet. I am trying to solve this problem. If i did it, i will share :)

Comment: @OsmanDurdag That's really strange, I have tried opening the link in several devices and it works for me. I apologize for the inconvenience. :D

Comment: You don't have to apologize :) Maybe this is a problem from me :)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me out, anyway. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you always call `fadeTo()`, even when you don't need to. When you scroll passed `y > 400` then `fadeTo(400, 0)` (fade out) is called. However when you scroll further down you keep calling `fadeTo(400, 0)` even though the element is no longer be visible.

I'm not entirely sure why the fade out takes so long, but I imagine it having something to do with chaining a lot of animation requests in a short time.

You can solve the issue by keeping track of the visibility of the element. I've added the following:

```
if (y <= 400 == isVisible) return;

// or if you find the above confusing
if (y <= 400 && isVisible || y > 400 && !isVisible) return;
```

This exits the callback early if the visibility doesn't have to be changed. This guard clause makes sure that `fadeTo()` is only called when it is actually needed.

Another thing that helps with performance is making sure you save `$("#intro-section")` in a variable beforehand. You should not forget that `$()` is a function that has to search the DOM for the provided query selector each time you call it. Imagine it as `findSelectorInDOM("#intro-section")`. Caching the result in a variable might speed things up considerably especially when you call `$()` often with the same argument.

```js
const $introSection = $("#intro-section");
let isVisible = $introSection.is(":visible");

$(document).scroll(function() {
  const y = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log(y);
  
  if (y <= 400 == isVisible) return;  
  isVisible = !isVisible;
  const opacity = +isVisible;
  
  console.log(`start fading to ${opacity}`);
  $introSection.fadeTo(400, opacity, () => {
    console.log(`done fading to ${opacity}`);
  });
});
```

```css
#intro-section {
  padding: 4rem;
}

#intro-section .row {
  padding: 4rem 8rem 7rem 8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="height: 300px">
  Scroll down!
</div>

<div id="intro-section">
  Intro
</div>

<div style="height: 100vh">
</div>
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I tried it out and it works too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the FadeTo multiple times when you scroll so it is still fading out when it tries to fadeIn. This code is tested and it works.

```
let fading = false;

jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(y);
    if(!fading) {
        fading = true;
        if (y > 400) {
            console.log('fading out');
            jQuery('#intro-section').fadeTo(400, 0.0, () => fading = false);
            console.log('done fading out');
        } else {
            console.log('fading in');
            jQuery('#intro-section').fadeTo(400, 1.0, () => fading = false);
            console.log('done fading in');
        }
    }


});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Thomas, your code seems to address the main problems and I have tried it out. That said, there is still some inconsistency in the behavior. While the fade-in/fade-out happens quickly, during quick scrolls, the function misses out on the main 400px value. I have uploaded another screencast of this with your code: https://imgur.com/a/WhQ52b2  Kindly have a look. (+1 for the given answer tho :D )

Answer (score 1):

I tried so much time, maybe this is what you are looking for :)

```js
let fadeInning = true;
let fadeOuting = false;
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log(y);
  if (y > 400) {
    if(!fadeOuting){
      fadeOuting = true;
      if(fadeInning){
        setTimeout(()=>{
          fadeInning = false;
          console.log('fading out');
          $('#intro-section').fadeTo(400, 0.0);
          console.log('done fading out');
        }, 400);
      }
      else{
        fadeInning = false;
        console.log('fading out');
        $('#intro-section').fadeTo(400, 0.0);
        console.log('done fading out');
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    if(!fadeInning){
      fadeInning = true;
      if(fadeOuting){
        setTimeout(()=>{
          fadeOuting = false;
          console.log('fading in');
          $('#intro-section').fadeTo(400, 1.0);
          console.log('done fading out');
        }, 400);
      }
      else{
        fadeOuting = false;
        console.log('fading in');
        $('#intro-section').fadeTo(400, 1.0);
        console.log('done fading in');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

#intro-section {
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="height: 300px">
  Scroll down!
</div>

<div id="intro-section">
  Intro
</div>

<div style="height: 100vh">
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly! However, It's a bit slow in the transition ( very little ) compared to the answer given by @3limin4t0r . I also tried it out with a separate variable for the inner-section tag created outside the callBack so that Jquery doesn't need to find that tag every time but I still get that tiny latency. Thanks a lot for spending your time trying to help me out, really appreciate it. :D